# Salvar Imagem em VARBINARY com C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5, imagem, varbinary

Como faço para pegar uma imagem recebida em um Form do `HTML` e gravar no banco em `VARBINARY` com `C#`?

Estou usando `C# ASP.NET MVC5 CORE`.

Comment: Compartilhe seu código onde você configura o campo VARBINARY. Outra dica, se os arquivos for maior que 1MB, é mais interessante utilizar FILESTREAM.

Comment: @GabrielColetta o banco já está criado com o campo VARBINARY e os arquivos não vão passar de 1mb, são miniaturas de imagens de logo de empresas.
Campos do banco: Cd_Empresa(int), Ds_Empresa(VARCHAR(60)) e Ds_Logo(VARBINARY)

Comment: @DiegoGrossi resolveu ?

Comment: Não @RovannLinhalis, tive que salvar em um diretório e gravei o caminho da imagem no banco. Quando vou chamar a imagem pego o caminho no banco.

Comment: Elabore uma resposta de como ficou sua solução e compartilhe com a comunidade, vlw

Answer (score 1):

No seu model, você precisa de uma propriedade do tipo IFormFile:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public IFormFile Arquivo {get;set;}
}
```

No seu objeto, ou classe POCO, precisa de uma propriedade do tipo byte[]:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public byte[] Foto {get;set;}
}
```

E Na action do seu controller, recebe o Model, passa pro stream e depois pro byte[] e então salva no banco:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(MyModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        MyObject obj = new MyObject();

        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await model.Arquivo.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
            //Recebo o stream, passo pra bytearray
            byte[] barray  = memoryStream.ToArray();
            //passo o array para o objeto
            obj.Foto = barray;

        }

        await _context.MyObjects.AddAsync(obj);
        _context.SaveChanges();
     }

     return View("Index");
}
```

Não se esqueça de, no form, adicionar a propriedade enctype="multipart/form-data"
Espero ter ajudado.

Edit. Coloquei primeiro para gravar como uma string (varchar) e não varbinary. Corrigido.

Comment: não consigo criar uma propriedade do tipo IFormFile no meu Model. O VS não reconhece e não habilita sugestão de correção.

Comment: certeza que está usando Asp.Net Core ?  https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Sim. No documento que você anexou, fala pra criar uma classe do tipo IFormFile e não uma propriedade. Isso procede, ou tenho que criar uma propriedade dentro de uma classe já existente e que não é uma interface?

Comment: eu fiz exatamente do jeito que postei, funciona perfeitamente. Obviamente tem várias outras formas de fazer. Se não estiver ou quiser usar um model com propriedades, coloque o IFormFile como parametro da action

Answer (score 0):

Tentei usar o código:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileWrapper file)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(Convert.ToString(file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        byte[] imagemArray = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);

        br.Close();
        fs.Close();

        return View("UploadFile");

    }
```

mas não sei qual tipo o action tem que receber o arquivo do HTML, já tentei string e HttpPostedFileBase, mas não dá certo.